# Problem running functions from a DLL file using ctypes in Object-oriented Python

Tags: python, dll, oop, automation, ctypes

I sure hope this won't be an already answered question or a stupid one. Recently I've been programming with several instruments. Trying to communicate between them in order to create a testing program.
However I've encoutered some problems with one specific instrument when I'm trying to call functions that I've "masked" out from the instruments DLL file.
When I use the interactive python shell it works perfectly (although its alot of word clobbering). But when I implement the functions in a object-oriented manner the program fails, well actually it doesn't fail it just doesn't do anything. This is the first method that's called: (ctypes and ctypes.util is imported)

```
    def init_hardware(self):
    """ Inits the instrument """
    self.write_log("Initialising the automatic tuner")
    version_string = create_string_buffer(80)
    self.error_string = create_string_buffer(80)
    self.name = "Maury MT982EU"
    self.write_log("Tuner DLL path: %s", find_library('MLibTuners'))
    self.maury = WinDLL('MlibTuners')
    self.maury.get_tuner_driver_version(version_string)
    if (version_string.value == ""):
        self.write_log("IMPORTANT: Error obtaining the driver version")
    else:
        self.write_log("Version number of the DLL: %s" % version_string.value)
    self.ThreeTypeLong = c_long * 3
```

Now that works swell, everything is perfect and I get perfect log-entries.
But when I try to run a method further into the program called:

```
def add_tuner_and_controller(self, name, serial_number, tuner_number=0):
    """ Adds the tuner to the driver object, controller is inside the tuner """
    self.write_log("Adding tuner %d and the built-in controller" % tuner_number)
    TempType = self.ThreeTypeLong()
    self.maury.add_controller(c_short(tuner_number), c_char_p(self.file_path), c_char_p(name), c_int(0), c_int(0), 
                              c_long(0), c_short(serial_number), self.error_string)
    self.maury.add_tuner(c_short(tuner_number), c_char_p(name), c_short(serial_number), c_short(0),
                            c_short(1), pointer(c_double()), TempType, pointer(c_double()), pointer(c_double()),
                            pointer(c_double()), self.error_string)
```

The program suddenly stops working/keeps running , nothing happenes when the "self.maury"-line is called. When I place everything in the init_hardware method it works perfectly so I'm guessing there's a slight memory "error" or something with the objective oriented structure. I really want it to remain this way, is there anyway to isolate the functions in this manner? or do I have to restrict myself to a big chunk of code?

---

**EDIT:**
*Documentation info*:
 
[Legend: The stars indicate pointers and the brackets indicate arrays]

**The add_tuner function adds or updates one tuner in the tuner driver object.**

```
short add_tuner(short tuner_number, char model[ ], short serial_number, short ctlr_num, short ctlr_port, short *no_of_motors, long max_range[ ], double *fmin, double *fmax, double *fcrossover, char error_string[ ])
```

**Output**: `no_motors, max_range (array of three numbers), fmin, fmax, fcrossover,error_string (80+ characters long), function-return->Error flag`

**The add_controller function adds or updates one controller in the tuner driver object**

```
short add_controller(short controller_number, char driver[ ], char model[ ], int timeout, int address, long delay_ms, char error_string[ ])
```

**Output**: `error_string, function-return->Error flag`

Comment: What do you pass as argument of the add_tuner_and_controller method?

Comment: the "name" of the tuner = "MT982EU" and serial_number=2316

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the only way to call the functions in the exported DLL was to use the DLL through a parameter in each method. (the program exports the dll and in each method called it will send it as a parameter).
It looks pretty ugly but that's the only way I found to be working for me. I even tried exporting the DLL as an class attribute. The system I'm working with is pretty hefty so I guess there is some boboo-code somewhere that makes it fail. Thanks for all the feedback and tips!

/Mazdak

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about your exact problem, but here's a couple general tips:

For those functions that you are calling outside of the constructor, I would strongly recommend setting their [`argtypes`](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#specifying-the-required-argument-types-function-prototypes) in the constructor as well.  Once you've declared the `argtypes`, you shouldn't need to cast all the arguments as `c_short`, `c_double`, etc.  Moreover, if you do accidentally pass an incorrect argument to a C function, Python will raise a runtime error instead of crashing within the DLL.

Another minor detail, but you should be using `x = 0;` [`byref(x)`](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#passing-pointers-or-passing-parameters-by-reference) or maybe [`POINTER`](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#pointers)`(c_double)()` instead of pointer(c_double()) in the tuner and controller.

I've been writing some ctypes classes in Python 2.6 recently as well, and I haven't seen any issues like what you're describing.  Since there apparently aren't any Python bug reports on that either, I strongly believe that there's just a minute detail that we are both overlooking in your method that is having a problem.

Comment: I'm currently using Python 2.5, is there perhaps an issue there?, safe to travel to a new version?

Comment: From http://python.org/download/:  "The current production versions are Python 2.6.2 and Python 3.1... Note that both Python 2.6 and 3.1 are considered stable production releases..."

Comment: I am using lot of modules with ctypes related code in production with Python 2.5 and I have not seen similar problem. Anyway, +1 for setting argtypes.

Answer (score 0):

Are any of the parameters in add-controller or add-tuner actually return values?

Strongly recommend that you define prototypes of your functions, rather than calling them direct with casts of all the parameters.

[I'm sure you've read this page already](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html), but the section you want to look at is Function Prototypes.  Makes the code much cleaner and easier to trace/debug.

Also -- as Mark Rushakoff mentions too -- using pointer(c_double()) and like in your call is pretty icky.  I have much better luck w/ POINTER(), and recommend again that you predeclare the value as a variable, and pass the variable in your function call.  Then at least you can examine its value afterward for strange behavior.

EDIT: So your prototype and call will look something like this:

```
prototype = WINFUNCTYPE(
    c_int,              # Return value (correct? Guess)
    c_short,            # tuner_number
    c_char_p,           # file_path
    c_char_p,           # name
    c_int,              # 0?
    c_int,              # 0?
    c_long,             # 0?
    c_short,            # serial_number
    c_char_p,           # error_string
)
# 1 input, 2 output, 4 input default to zero (I think; check doc page)
paramflags = (1, 'TunerNumber' ), (1, 'FilePath' ), (1, 'Name' ), ...
AddController = prototype(('add_controller', WinDLL.MlibTuners), paramflags)
```

Then your call is much cleaner:

```
arg1 = 0
arg2 = 0
arg3 = 0
AddController(tuner_number, self.file_path, name, arg1, arg2, arg3, 
    serial_number, self.error_string)
```

Comment: Well this doesn't actually solve my issue, but thanks for the hints anyways! so you want me to declare the prototypes and set the paramflags in the constructor? I understand that the error will be easier to find if it was a syntax error. But this isn't, I think. I've changed and moved everything to the constructor and then it works. But as soon as a method is called from my running class it always get stuck at the "self.maury" line. Maybe i should have the DLL as a parameter to every method?